# Download HTML from YouTube

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to download YouTube HTML in my ASP.Net Application with :

```
string downloaded = string.Empty;
try
{
      String url = String.Format(YouTubeDownloadedVideo, videoID);

      WebClient Client = new WebClient();
      downloaded = Client.DownloadString(url);
}
catch { }
```

But i don't get the full HTML, i try the same code in a Console application that i created and it's work perfectly.

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Remove that exception eating `catch` block!

Comment: Time to use your **uber debugging skills**! Put down some breakpoints, including one on the entry brace to the `catch` block. Tell us if you're getting a fragment HTML or no HTML at all.

Comment: Did you try using 'HtmlAgilityPack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the webclient you can just use webresponse if you only need the HTML in a string.

```
    private string GetWebPage(string URL)
    {
        string strHTMLPage = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            if (webResponse != null)
            {
                StreamReader oSR = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                strHTMLPage = oSR.ReadToEnd();
                oSR.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            strHTMLPage = "";
        }

        return strHTMLPage;
    }
```